# How Do I Create a Custom Guest User?

Tags: launchd, user-account, login, customization, guest-account

I have a mac that will be used by myself (admin) and a few other people (second account). I don't want data to persist between logins on this second account, similar to how the Guest Account works. The problem with the guest account is, it resets applications placed in the dock between logins as well as resetting the desktop wallpaper (which I would like to keep the same throughout logins). My solution was to set up a standard account, lock the dock using `defaults write com.apple.Dock size-immutable -bool yes` and set the wallpaper manually. As for the data, I would like all files that have been downloaded or transferred by the user to be wiped when the user logs out (or equally, when the next user logs in). Alternatively, If there is a way for the Guest Account to not reset the dock and wallpaper on logout, this would also work. Thanks!